# Enter OG audience to a node with Rules

Tags: rules, organic-groups

How to add a specific Organic Group to a node in the action-step with rules (7.2)?

I can't figure out which action and which options i should use. Now i've something like

```
**action**
Set a data value
Parameter: Data: [node:og-group-ref:0]
```

But this isn't correct. How can i give the og-group-ref the correct value (the OG is in this case nid 180).

Comment: I hesitate to post it as an actual answer (I might convert my comment to it if it helps) ... But instead of using "Set a data value", you could try to use "Add to list" instead ... The reason why I think this alternative should work, is because of the ":0" part at the end of "node:og-group-ref:0" (which indicates "node:og-group-ref" is an array of values).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct answer, but i found a different way. If the og_group_ref is **set to checkboxes** (these checkboxes are essential) (look at admin/structure/types/manage/[YOURCONTENTTYPE]/fields/og_group_ref), you can set the default audience. 
Now i just hide the field 'audience' for certain roles and new nodes are saved to the right OG.

Again, this isn't the way i asked to do it with rules. When someone knows the right answer how to do it, i'm eager to hear it.